# toLocaleString price without decimal zeroes

Tags: javascript, formatting, numbers, locale, currency

I am wondering how to efficiently remove the decimal zeroes from a price while keeping the 2 decimals if there

So if a price is `135.00` it should become `135`.

If a price is `135.30` however it should keep both decimals.

If a price is `135.38` it can keep the decimals.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
const currency = 'EUR';
const language = 'NL';

var localePrice = (amount) => {
  const options = {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency
  };

  return amount.toLocaleString(language, options);
}
```

Now I could use regex or something similar but I am hoping there is an easier way to get this done.

I have made a JSFiddle which illustrates my problem which makes it easy to play with the code.

https://jsfiddle.net/u27a0r2h/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a function checking if the number is an integer or not and  use a condition within your localePrice function to apply your formatting (playing with slice to remove the decimal) :

```js
function isInt(n) {
   return n % 1 === 0;
}

const currency = 'EUR';
const language = 'NL';


var localePrice = (amount) => {
  const options = {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency
  };

  if (isInt(amount)){
    return amount.toLocaleString(language, options).slice(0, -3);
  }
  else {
    return amount.toLocaleString(language, options);
  }
}

document.querySelector('.price').innerHTML = localePrice(135.21);

document.querySelector('.price-zeroes').innerHTML = localePrice(135.00);

document.querySelector('.price-with-one-zero').innerHTML = localePrice(135.30);
```

Comment: This will not work depending on the currency and language used. Some imply to have the current symbol appended after the number.

Comment: Thing is the question is only about formating the number ;)

Answer (score 5):

Try just add `minimumFractionDigits: 0` to your options, like:

```
const currency = 'EUR';
const language = 'NL';

var localePrice = (amount) => {
  const options = {
    style: 'currency',
    currency: currency,
    minimumFractionDigits: 0
  };

  return amount.toLocaleString(language, options);
}
```

Comment: You are right, it will round to 135.3 which is not what was asked.
Anyway, will leave it in case it is what someone else is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The first answer using minimumFractionDigits is the good approach, just set it to 0 or 2 depending on the case.

```js
amount = 5.20
amount.toLocaleString('fr-FR', { style: 'currency', 
                                 currency: 'EUR', 
                                 minimumFractionDigits: Math.ceil(amount % 1) * 2 })
```